# Use Google Apps Script (GAS) Java Script Libraries in regular GCP Web Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, migration

I developed a successful Web App project based on Google Apps Script (GAS). Two limitations of GAS get more and more critical:

- File size limitation of 50MB
- The run time limitation of 15 minutes

Is there a way to migrate the existing GAS web app to a "regular" GCP Web App without changing the GAS code of the Web App?
Working with Google Drive with e.g. `DriveApp.createFile` or Google Sheets with `SpreadsheetApp.openById` is something we would like to keep.

Is this possible ?
Has anybody done a successful migration?
Can anybody roughly point out the required step or point to useful resources?

I have researched the available GAS and GCP documentation but could not find a documentation of the required steps or even information on the feasibility.